# How to display images of a array?

Tags: image, meteor, upload, meteor-autoform, cfs

I'm using these packages

> aldeed:collection2,
>
> aldeed:autoform,
>
> cfs:standard-packages,
>
> yogiben:autoform-file,
>
> cfs:filesystem.

```
{{#with FS.GetFile "images" pictures}}
        <img src="{{this.url}}" alt="" class="card-img-bottom">
      {{/with}}

Images = new FS.Collection("images",{
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images")],
  filter:{
    allow:{
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  }
});
Images.allow({
  insert: function(userId,fileObj){
    return true;
  },
  update:function(userId,fileObj){
    return true;
  },
  download: function(userId,fileObj){
    return true;
  }
});
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.allow({
  insert:function(userId,fileObj){
    return true;
  },
  update:function(userId,fileObj){
    return true;
  }
});
PostSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  title:{
    type: String,
    autoform:{
      label:false,
      type:"textarea",
      placeholder:"Comparte con la comunidad"
    }
  },
  pictures:{
    type:[String],
    optional: true,
    label: " "
  },
  'pictures.$':{
    autoform:{
      type:"fileUpload",
      collection: 'images',
      selectFileBtnTemplate: 'mySelectFileBtn',
      previewTemplate: 'myFilePreview',
      uploadProgressTemplate: 'myUploadProgressTemplate'
    }
  },
  author:{
    type:String,
    label: "Author",
    autoValue: function(){
      return this.userId
    },
    autoform:{
      type:"hidden"
    }
  },
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    label: "created At",
    autoValue:function(){
      return new Date()
    },
    autoform:{
      type:"hidden"
    }
  }
});
Posts.attachSchema(PostSchema);
```

I have this error

> Exception in queued task: Error: Invalid selector: tzYd8ocD9xhvCCfk7

When it is not array if the picture show

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the information you have provided does not show how you are publishing the images, so perhaps you might want to show that too ?

Comment: You need to publish the images on the server and subscribe to them on the client before you can display them